# Displaying key-value-pairs out of an array by using a template

Tags: meteor

I want to display key-value pairs stored in an array (derived from a Session-JSON variable) by using the #each template directive. How can I get access (if possible) to the fields of objects in an array.

Sorry, if this is a question that has been already answered, but I didn't find an appropriate answer here.

Here is some sample code (part of a template helper):

```
attributes: function () {
        var attributes = [];
        attributes = [{key: test1, value: 1}, {key: test3, value: 2}, {key: test3, value: 3}];
        return attributes;
    },
```

In the template, I used "this" or "this.key". Both didn't work the way as expected.

Thanks for any tipps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined variables `test1`, `test3` ? It looks like you put `test1` and `test3` without ", so it means js is trying to find variables with such names. That's why you couldn't see `this.key` working.

```
 var attributes = [];
 attributes = [{key: "test1", value: 1}, {key: "test2", value: 2}, {key: "test3", value: 3}];
 return attributes;
```

In template:

```
{{#each attributes}}
   {{this.key}} : {{this.value}}<br>
{{/each}}
```

Output:

```
test1 : 1<br>
test2 : 2<br>
test3 : 3<br>
```

[Check here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/FucBnDbZQnBWFR8Bh)

Comment: Great, works sometimes you forget the most simple things...! Thanks so much!